# Outlook-like search in cxGrid

Tags: delphi, devexpress, tcxgrid

Is there anyone who know if it is possible to have a [cxGrid](http://www.devexpress.com/Products/VCL/ExQuantumGrid/Index.xml) have a searchbar like in Outlook contacts where you just press one letter and the first contact with that letter in lastname is shown?

I would love to see an example of this, but so far my search everywhere has been without result.

Comment: Did you try asking this question to [DevExpress Support](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/)?

Comment: If the table is linked with a TDataset then filter the dataset onKeyUp

Comment: I have not asked it there and I am not going to.
Don't ask why - it is personal.

Comment: How does the answer to your question affect the answer that belongs here at Stack Overflow, @Ngln?

Comment: The behavior you describe of Outlook's contact list is not what I observe. For me, it jumps to the first contact whose last name *starts with* the typed letter or, if there are no such contacts, to the first contact with a name starting *later* than the typed letter. (For example, I have no contacts whose names start with *R*, so when I press R, it jumps to my first *S* contact. Earlier in the list, I have a *B* contact whose name contains an *R*, but Outlook doesn't take me there.)

Comment: @Rod Kennedy    Maybe I wasn't so clear about what I was looking for. But it is just what you are describing I would like to add to a form with contacts.
Now I have a grouping on the first letter of the companyname, but I don't think it looks nice are I find it a bit confusing.

Comment: No time for an answer with code but look at the following to help implement custom searching in code:
TcxCustomGridTableController.IncSearchingText in the ExpressQuantumGrid help file and the TcxDataControllerSearch Object
 in the ExpressDataController help file.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable de Filter bar in CxGrid doing the next steps:

At the Object Inspector you must change some properties

Step 1:

At the DBTableView.FilterRow property change:

```
DBTableView1 - FilterRow - ApplyChanges = fracImmedialety
DBTableView1 - FilterRow - Visible = True
DBTableView1 - FilterRow - InfoText = to add the text "Click here for filter creation (for substring search, begin with * character)"
```

Step 2:

At the DBTableView.DataController property change:

```
DBTableView1 -DataController-Filter-PercentWildCards = * ( will put instead of percent a star)
DBTableView1 -DataController-Filter-Options-fcoCaseInsensitive = True (any register)

DBTableView1 -DataController-Filter-Options-fcoShowOperatorDescription = True
```